# Getting integer output for dictionary values in python

Tags: python

The following code is used to convert '.csv' file to 'json' file. While converting it makes every data items of dictionary to string. How to get the data converted to integers. The line number 44 adds keys and data to the dictionary. This is actually a dictionary of dictionary. The dictionary is then written on the json file in the line number 53.

```
import sys, getopt
import csv
import json

#Get Command Line Arguments
def main(argv):
    input_file = ''
    output_file = ''
    format = ''
    try:
        opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv,"hi:o:f:",["ifile=","ofile=","format="])
    except getopt.GetoptError:
        print('1062368.csv -i <path to inputfile> -o <path to outputfile> -f <dump/pretty>')
        sys.exit(2)
    for opt, arg in opts:
        if opt == '-h':
            print('1062368.csv -i <path to inputfile> -o <path to outputfile> -f <dump/pretty>')
            sys.exit()
        elif opt in ("-i", "--ifile"):
            input_file = arg
        elif opt in ("-o", "--ofile"):
            output_file = arg
        elif opt in ("-f", "--format"):
            format = arg
    print(output_file)
    read_csv(input_file, output_file, format)

#Read CSV File
def read_csv(file, json_file, format):
    csv_rows = {}
    with open(file) as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        title = reader.fieldnames
        #print(len(title))  = 4
        n = 0
        p = 0
        month = 1
        day = 1
        file_name = 2000
        csv_rows[month] = {}
        #the following loop runs the number of rows times i.e. 6412
        for row in reader:
            csv_rows[month][day] = {}
            csv_rows[month][day] = {title[i]:row[title[i]] for i in range(len(title))}
            day = day + 1
            if day == 30:
                day = 1
                month = month + 1
                csv_rows[month] = {}
            n = n+1
            if n == 365:
                temp_file = (str)(file_name+p)
                write_json(csv_rows, temp_file+'.json', format)
                n = 0
                p = p+1
                csv_rows={}
                month = 1
                day = 1
                csv_rows[month] = {}
        #write_json(csv_rows, json_file, format)

#Convert csv data into json and write it
def write_json(data, json_file, format):
    with open(json_file, "w") as f:
        if format == "pretty":
            f.write(json.dumps(data, sort_keys=False, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '),encoding="utf-8",ensure_ascii=False))
        else:
            f.write(json.dumps(data))

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Comment: Cool. What's your question? This is basically a dump of code.

Comment: If you just wanted to know how to convert a string to an integer, you didn't need to post all that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plucking this bit out of your confusing question:

> How to get the data converted to integers

Use `int()`, like so:

```
string_value = '5'
int_value = int(string_value)
```

Comment: Better even to try to catch a `ValueError` exception when trying to convert int to str.

Comment: @blacksite One thing at a time.  :-)